# Nginx Caching 404

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, nginx

I am using WordPress with Nginx but whenever I try to enable caching of static files they turn to 404 not found.

This is my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  _;

# SSL configuration
listen 443 ssl default_server;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shivampaw.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shivampaw.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 30m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_buffer_size 8k;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    location / {
        root   /home/shivam/sites/shivampaw.com;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /home/shivam/sites/shivampaw.com;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}

gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json applicationx-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

include wordpress/wordpress.conf;
```

And this is the WordPress.conf file:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
# Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
}


# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
```

With that, it works fine. But if I add

```
# Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

To the end of wordpress.conf and restart nginx and reload my site all the static files come up with 404.

So I have to comment that caching out and it works fine.

Any ideas?

[image: 404s]
[image: Single 404]

This means that if I include wp-rocket.conf (I use it) it also gives a 404 because wp-rocket.conf has caching stuff in it.

So basically, why can't i cache static files?

Comment: It's because you've defined your root in the root location block. So the other location blocks don't know about it. This is bad practice (see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)). These location blocks don't know where to look for the files. You should have the `root  /home/shivam/sites/shivampaw.com;` above your `location / {` block and then add the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args` to each of your static blocks. Another way to do it is to keep your config, but add `alias /path/to/static/files/;` to each block.

Comment: Thanks @KeenanLawrence - feel free to post that as an answer :)

Comment: It's a please @shiv. Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you've defined your root in the root location block. So the other location blocks don't know about it. This is bad practice (see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)). These location blocks don't know where to look for the files.

You should have the `root /home/shivam/sites/shivampaw.com;` above your `location / {` block and then add the `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args` to each of your static blocks.

Another way to do it is to keep your config, but add `alias /path/to/static/files/;` to each block.